# Can my Huawei U8220-6 get an upgrade?

Tags: updates, huawei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will my phone get the Android 2.2 update (FroYo)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/when-will-my-phone-get-the-android-2-2-update-froyo)

I have a Huawei U8220-6, bought in China. This is NOT T-Mobile pulse branded, so I wanted to know if there is anyway to put Froyo (or Eclair) in it. My current version is 1.6.